# How to use 'order by null' in spring data jpa?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am writing SQL using @Query in spring data jpa.
Because you are using mysql db.
I want to get rid of file sorting using ordery by null.

when i did

```
@Query(" SELECT A FROM TABLE A ORDER BY NULL")
```

You cannot use NULL with the syntax `Can't resolve symbol 'NULL'`.

Is there any way to solve this problem?
QueryDSL is deprecated.

Comment: If you dont want sorting there is no need to have `ORDER BY ...` clause at all, just remove it from your query. e.g. `"SELECT A FROM TABLE A"`

Comment: If you are using spring data jpa, there is absolutely no need to write simple queries yourself. Use either the `JpaRepository` or `CrudRepository` and you get them for free